# SOLVED In deployment my Rails App save pictures in a new one capistrano release directory different from the current release

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, deployment, capistrano, carrierwave

what happen to my rails app is very very strange.

To upload the picture that belong to an online article in my app I decide to use carrierwave. All the pictures are in a remote url location and to fetch the image and save them in the server I use a rails worker

**ISSUE**

When the app save a new **feed** every **article** (feedlist) that belongs to this feed is stored in a postgresql db using this worker (Feed has_many Feedlists):

```
class AddNewFeedWorker

  include Sidekiq::Worker

  sidekiq_options :queue => :default
  sidekiq_options :retry => false #when fail don't repeat

.
.
.

def perform(feed_id)  

feed.entries.each do |entry|  

  entry.published.nil? ? @datafeedlist == Time.now() : @datafeedlist = entry.published
  unless Feedlist.where(:guid => entry.id).exists?

  begin
    @object = LinkThumbnailer.generate(entry.url)
    @img_url = @object.images.last.to_s 
  rescue Exception => exc
    logger.error("Message for the log file: #{exc.message} for the feed id: #{@feed.id}")
    @img_url = entry.image
  end 

  sleep 1

  @f = Feedlist.create!(
    :rssurl       => @feed.rssurl,
    :name         => entry.title,
    :summary      => entry.summary,
    :url          => entry.url,    
    :published_at => @datafeedlist,
    :guid         => entry.id,
    :image        => entry.media_thumbnail_url,
    :remote_article_picture_url => @img_url,
    :content      => entry.content,
    :feed_id      => @feed.id,
    :user_id      => @user.id
  )

  end
end

.
.
.

end # end perform method
end # end worker
```

this line **:remote_article_picture_url => @img_url** is a carrierwave notation that fetch from a remote location url a picture and save it in your server.

I said to **capistrano** to save alle pictures in a shared directory for all releases

**my_rails_capistrano_directory/shared/uploads**

BUT the app instead to save in this directory the pictures create a new one directory and save there alle the pictures

my_rails_capistrano_directory/releases/20200327071103/uploads

but my current app is in the current release directory

my_rails_capistrano_directory/releases/20200429020251

**MY QUESTION IS WHY THAT'S HAPPEN?**

To more information you can check the follow code

**CAPISTRANO**

config/initializers/carrierwave.rb

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.permissions = 0600
  config.directory_permissions = 0700
  config.storage = :file
  config.root = Rails.root
end
```

config/deploy.rb

```
append :linked_dirs, "log", "tmp/pids", "tmp/cache", "tmp/sockets", "vendor/bundle", "uploads"
```

**UPLOADER** (I choose to upload in the local machine. The **uploads** directory is inside the root app but outside from **/public** dir)

```
class CategoryLogoUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

  storage :file

  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end

  version :middle do
     process resize_to_fit: [400, 300]
  end

  version :thumb do
     process resize_to_fit: [120, 120]
  end

end
```

**MODEL**

```
class Feedlist < ActiveRecord::Base

  mount_uploader :article_picture, CategoryLogoUploader

end
```

**VIEW** this code add a new Feed to belong to an user

```
<%= form_for([@feed.user, @feed]) do |f| %>
  <% if @feed.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@feed.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this feed from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @feed.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

<div class="form-group">
  <%= I18n.t("feed.title") %> <br />
  <%= f.text_field :title %>
</div> <br />

<div class="form-group">
  <%= I18n.t("feed.insert") %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :rssurl, required: true %>
</div> <br />

<div class="form-group">
  <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, :value => current_user.id %>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <%= I18n.t("feed.tags_list") %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :tag_list, required: true %>
</div> 

<div class="form-group">    
  <%= f.submit @feed.new_record? ? "#{I18n.t("feed.insert_button")}" : "#{I18n.t("feed.update_button")}", class: "btn btn-info btn-rounded"%>
</div>

<% end %>
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
def create
  @feed 
  if @feed.save                   
    AddNewFeedWorker.perform_async(@feed.id)                                     
    redirect_to root_path
  else
    render 'new', :notice => "something went wrong"
  end
end
```

FINALLY AT THE END I FIXED THE ISSUE!

simply restart sidekiq and redis and after that everything work like a charm :))

thanks anyway

Comment: Welcome to SO. You're abusing font faces. Please see "[How do I format my posts...](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)". Formatting helps us understand your question, but abusing it detracts and makes it harder to follow your question, logic and code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure your `config.root` to the shared directory.

See "[Unable to configure storage path with CarrierWave using `config.root` #2192](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/issues/2192)".

Comment: Hi Amit ... thanks for your answer but your solution doen't work

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure but seems like the application is not restarted after deployment and still sits in **20200327071103**. This is why you get uploaded files to old release dir.

Another thing I would look is if links are and matching shared dir. For example:

```
 my_rails_capistrano_directory/releases/20200327071103/uploads ->
 my_rails_capistrano_directory/shared/uploads
```

Comment: this directory my_rails_capistrano_directory/releases/2020042902025 is create after the restart 

but this one directory my_rails_capistrano_directory/releases/20200327071103/uploads is create when the app upload the pictures ... very strange

Another thing that I noticed is that if I put the worker's code in an action the picture are uploaded in the right directory my_rails_capistrano_directory/shared/public ... according my carrierwave setting ... thats really weird!